# Drupal pager in views

Tags: 7, views

I have a view created for product categories, now I want pager, I configure the settings by displaying specified num of items instead of all items, now I am getting the specified num of items on a page but not getting the pager when I added more than specified number of items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In view, select full/mini pager & do necessary settings. Please check screeshots below

Change pager type
[image]

Change settings
[image]

Comment: Thanku vishal for ur reply, I do the same as you told me, now I got previous and next links as i required in my preview not on actual display of page

Comment: @nomeer You might forgot to save your view :) I guess ;)

Comment: As @KrishnaMohan said, please check if you have saved the view.

Comment: Actually I am new to drupal krishna mohan and vishal patil, now its working :)